# Python's re.split() not removing all matched characters

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

This is driving me absolutely nuts. I am positive that the entire date range at the start of the string is being matched by the regex. Yet, when I do re.split, an `8` hangs behind. What's going on here and how can I split on that date range (in some cases it might be at the start and in the middle of the string, hence the split)?

```
import re
a = "09/05/2018-12/18/2018 Lecture Wednesday 01:30PM - 02:45PM, Room to be Announced"
b = r"([0-9]|\/|-){21}"
print re.split(b, a)
```

Result

```
['', '8', ' Lecture Wednesday 01:30PM - 02:45PM, Room to be Announced']
```

Comment: Try something like this by use of lookbehind: `(?<=[\d/-]{21})\s+` Your current regex captures the last match `8` as split sequence. [Test your regex eg here](https://regex101.com/r/LBeYFF/1/).

Comment: works when I do it like this `[0-9\/\-]{21}`

Comment: @bobblebubble Should work but look behind is slow comparatively

Comment: @Cfreak You are right, it's very slow for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for `re.split`:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

You do have a capturing group, and the last thing it matches is the character `8`.  That's why `8` is returned.

You can use a non-capturing group instead:

```
>>> b = r"(?:[0-9]|\/|-){21}"
           ^^ note these two characters added
>>> re.split(b, a)
['', ' Lecture Wednesday 01:30PM - 02:45PM, Room to be Announced']
```

Or you could put all the choices in a single character class, and not need a group at all:

```
>>> b = r"[-/0-9]{21}"
>>> re.split(b, a)
['', ' Lecture Wednesday 01:30PM - 02:45PM, Room to be Announced']
```